# Generate reCAPTCHA public\private keys for tests purposes only

Tags: recaptcha

Is there any way to generate keys for development (I want to play with reCAPTCHA in my small local project)? I tried to do this on reCAPTCHA web site, but when I entered "localhost" in domain field and pressed "create" button It always get 404 error.

Comment: For future reference, ALL reCAPTCHA keys are enabled for localhost. (source: http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

even the system name works...to get the public and private keys

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your domain on http field and check "Enable this key on all domains". Then recaptcha will be working on your localhost.

Comment: Hm, now I try again to enter "localhost" and all works fine, I got my public and private keys. Oh, I found that all attempts that I entered earlier was saved and now displaying in "My Site" section :). it seems that the service didn't worked properly for a while.